# How to exclude filesystems with ansible

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, system-administration

I'm writing a playbook the change file and folders permissions on a Linux server.
Until know it is working and looks like this:

```
-
  name: Playbook to change file and directory permissions
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    DIR: '{{ target_dir }}'
    FILE: '{{ target_file }}'
    PERMISSIONS: '{{ number }}'
    OWNER: '{{ target_owner }}'
    GROUP: '{{ target_group }}'

  tasks:

    - name: Checking if the directory exists
      stat:
        path: '{{ DIR }}'
      register: dir_status

    - name: Checking if the file exists
      stat:
        path: '{{ FILE }}'
      register: file_status

    - name: Report if directory exists
      debug:
        msg: "Directory {{ DIR }} is present on the server"
      when: dir_status.stat.exists and dir_status.stat.isdir

    - name: Report if file exists
      debug:
        msg: "File {{ FILE }} is present on the server"
      when: file_status.stat.exists

    - name: Applying new permissions
      file:
          path: '{{ DIR }}/{{ FILE }}'
          state: file
          mode: '0{{ PERMISSIONS }}'
          owner: '{{ OWNER }}'
          group: '{{ GROUP }}'
```

But what I need is if the user that gonna execute the playbook in rundeck wanna change permissions on the (/boot /var /etc /tmp /usr) directories tell ansible to not try doing that and throw an error message.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking ... the title suggests that you don't want to allow ansible to change certain directories/files. In the text it sounds as if you're asking how to change them, anyway.  That said: please give us the **exact** error message. *something like* isn't really a good basis for an analysis.

Comment: Hi ! Sorry if I'm not being clear. 
What I want is that when the playbook is executed if one of those directories (/ boot, / etc, / usr) is passed by parameter it stops sending an error message saying that permissions cannot be changed on system directories

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want the change to happen (**bad idea!!**) or do you want ansible to not try doing that? Or do you just want to suppress the error messages?  P.S.: Please edit the question with the clearer request(s) rather than answering in the comments. Here at [so] a question is supposed to be clear, rather than demanding that one read a whole thread to understand what you really want.

Comment: I want ansible to not try that and throw and error message to the user

Comment: @tink I have already corrected the question, I hope that now it is understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question that you like to [fail with custom message](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) [when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) a variable `DIR` contains one of the values `/boot`, `/var`, `/etc`, `/tmp` or `/usr`.

To do so you may use

```
- name: You can't work on {{ DIR }}
  fail:
    msg: The system may not work on {{ DIR }} according ...
   when: '"/boot" or "/var" or "/etc" or "/tmp" or "/usr" in DIR'
```

There is also a [`meta`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html)_module which can `end_play` when condition are met.

```
  tasks:
  - meta: end_play
    when: '"/boot" or "/var" or "/etc" or "/tmp" or "/usr" in DIR'
```

Both, `fail` and  `end_play`, you can combine with different variables for certain use cases.

```
when: "'download' or 'unpack' in ansible_run_tags"
when: ( "DMZ" not in group_names )
```

Thanks to

- [Run an Ansible task only when the variable contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496911/)
- [Ansible - Execute task when variable contains specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924706/)

Please take note that you are constructing the full path by concatenating `{{ DIR }}/{{ FILE }}` at the end. The above mentioned simple approach will not handle an empty `DIR` and `FILE`name with path included. Test cases could be

```
DIR: ""
FILE "/tmp/test"

DIR: "/"
FILE: "tmp/test"
```

Maybe you like to perform the test on the full filepath or [test what a variable begins with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434266/).

In respect to the comments from [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator) and [seshadri-c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13968097/seshadri-c) you may also try the approach of the [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#examples)_module

```
- name: Check for allowed directories
  assert:
    that:
      -  DIR in ["/boot", "/etc", "/var", "/tmp", "/usr"]
    quiet: true
    fail_msg: "The system may not work on {{ DIR }} according ..."
    success_msg: "Path is OK."
```

Comment: One more module (and the best suited one in this scenario IMO) is [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)

Comment: Also, I'd have the `when` condition as `when: DIR in ["/boot", "/etc", "/var", "/usr"]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation ! It was really helpful